# Probability question. Roulette dozens bet occurring consecutively.

Tags: probability, gambling

Hello Mathematics Guru's,

Can I first caveat this question by saying, I'm wholly aware the house always has a mathematical edge if you play long enough in Roulette, but i am interested to know the following all the same.

I would like to know the percentage chance of the following occurring playing Roulette.

I like to bet on 2 of the dozen bets, which pays 2:1. Specifically the middle column (13-24) and high column (25-36) at the time covering approximately 64.8% of the board.

So my question is,  what is the percentage chance of the low column numbers (1-12) and the zero occurring, ie the numbers i'm not betting on hitting consecutively?   Specifically, 6, 7 and 8 times in a row.

Many thanks

Keir

Comment: Can you figure out the probability of [that event] happening one time?

Comment: Yes, the chance of the first dozen (1-12) or the Zero hitting is 35.1% probability.   Any single no including the zero is 2.7% and any dozen is 32.4%

Comment: Great! Now raise that probability ($0.351$) to the power of 6, 7, or 8.

Comment: Many thanks, i've worked it out!